# importing outlook contacts

Tags: microsoft-outlook, contacts, transfer

I am trying to import outlook contact files from a pulled hard drive. I get to the folder under Users\username\AppData\local\Microsoft\Outlook I found a .pst file but when I try to add import the file it says it is already associated with the mail account. If no contacts show up does that mean this .pst file has no contacts?

Comment: I figured it out, I was choosing the local hardrive not the old one .

Comment: can't until 8 hours has passed, but i will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I was choosing the local hardrive not the old one